# Time Machine and case-sensitive HFS

Tags: time-machine, backup, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

Time Machine defaults to formatting a new drive to Journaled HFS+ (case-sensitive), if you set up the drive from within Time Machine itself. However, my main drive (the one Time Machine will be backing up) is case-insensitive.

Firstly, will this ever become a problem? I've seen [answers which discuss the pros and cons of using case-sensitivity](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8016/hfs-case-sensitive-or-case-insensitive-which-type-to-use-for-the-primary-dri), and [which discuss problems using a case-sensitive Time Machine disk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25710/how-do-i-restore-a-case-sensitive-journaled-time-machine-backup-to-a-case-insen). However, if my source disk is case--insensitive, is it ever possible for the case-sensitive Time Machine backup to get into a state where it can't copy files back to the case-insensitive drive?

If it could become a problem, what is the best way to change my drive to case-insensitive -- With the added twist that the partition is encrypted? The [answers I've seen](https://serverfault.com/questions/166059/how-to-convert-a-case-insensitive-fs-to-case-sensitive-on-macos-x-10-6-1) seem to imply that the only way is to create a new case-insensitive partition, and copy all the file over to it. However, because the drive contains an encrypted partition, Disk Utility limits me to only splitting the drive into 2 partitions, or merging those partitions back together; I can't delete the encrypted, case-sensitive partition without completely formatting the drive.

I don't have the space to temporarily copy my backup drive's contents over while I erase the external drive (internal drive is too small, and I don't have a third drive.)